# Sonata: Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached.. when embedding forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

EDIT: For anyone interested on solving the same issue, that did the trick:

```php
echo `'xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250' >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`
```

---

I've created 3 Admins for 3 entities linked to each other, where A Admin is embedding B Admin and B Admin embeds C Admin. B entity has a ManyToOne relation with A and B entity.

A entity embeds B entity with the following code:

```php
$formMapper->add('b', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
    'by_reference' => false
), array(
    'edit' => 'inline',
    'inline' => 'table',
    'sortable'  => 'position'
) );
```

B entity embeds C entity with the following one:

```php
 $formMapper->add( 'c', 'sonata_type_model', array( 
    'required'  => true, 
    'label'     => ucfirst( $this->trans( 'c', array(), $this->translationDomain, $this->langCode ) )
    ), array( 'edit' => 'list' ) );
```

Note: changing `'edit' => 'list'` in favour of `'edit' => 'standard'` avoids the following error.

Placing `array( 'edit' => 'list' )` on B Admin entity on a `sonata_type_model` form type gives the following error while editing A enity. If instead `array( 'edit' => 'standard' )` is used then no error is output:

```php
Sonata: Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in myProject/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Lexer.php on line 756
```

The tricky or curious thing is that no matter if edit is list or standard if i go to B admin to edit it. the problem only appears if i edit B embedded into A with edit list option set. And this is happening to me in some other entities where i implemented the same behaviour.

Here are A, B and C entity and how they link each other:

A entity:

```php
class A
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=4)
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true ) */
    protected $b;
}
```

B entity:

```php
class B
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=4)
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id
    /**
     *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="C", inversedBy="b", cascade={"persist"} )
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="c_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $c;
    /**
     *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="b", cascade={"persist"} )
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $a;
}
```

C entity:

```php
Class C
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=4)
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="c", cascade={"persist"} ) */
    private $b;
}
```

To be able to take a look at it all you can use sonata demo project to check for a similar behaviour.
As you can see it is the same use case which can be found on Sonata Project demo where Gallery is linked against GalleHasMedias which links against Media: http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/sonata/media/gallery/255/edit?context=default As you can see, GalleryHasMedia has a ManyToOne relation with Gallery and another one with Media so when you edit a Gallery ou can see a `sonata_type_model` with `edit' => 'inline','inline' => 'table',` so a GalleryHasMedia is embedded inside Gallery form in order to be able to add new Medias which are going to be linked with the current Gallery and stored inside `GalleryHasMedia`.

Has any one faced a situation like the exposed one? Hope someone could point to the right direction or help to get a clue on what's going on.

PD: For me it seems like B and C entities are linking/embedding each other in an endless loop. But as said, 3 Admins are working great separately (while A does not embeds B).

Comment: That did the trick: echo 'xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250' >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini

Comment: Thanks that's was driving my nuts for a day, with Symphony while running phpunits

Comment: Instead of editing your question with your solution please provide an actual answer so the community knows this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested on solving the same issue, that did the trick:

```
echo `'xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250' >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem with servers running xdebug. You must increase the nesting level by increasing the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in your xdebug.ini configuration. Setting it to something like 250 should suffice.

One quick way to add the setting is to do this on your linux server:

```
echo `'xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250' >> /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer lifo but as you already should noticed it was already solved via edit.